# Connecting On-Prem network via transit gateway in the other aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpn, transit-gateway

I have 2 `aws` accounts, where `A` is connected to `On-Prem` via `transit gateway`, and `B` is connected to `A` via `peering connection`. All works fine, thus I have connectivity from `A` to `On-Prem`, and from `A` to `B`. The challenge is to have connectivity from `B` to `On-Prem` without creating yet another `transit gateway`. Is it possible?

```
  +---------+
  |         |
  | On-Prem |
  |         |
  +---------+
    |    ^
    v    |
  +--------------------------+
  |          | AWS Account A |
  | AWS TGW  +---------------+
  |          | Peering Conn  |
  +--------------------------+
                     ^      |
                     |      v
             +---------------+
             | Peering Conn  |
             +---------------+
             | AWS Account B |
             +---------------+
```

It seems I have the routing, SGs, ACLs - all correct but it still doesn't work. Since I cannot see any packet flows on AWS infra it's very difficult to debug. Also I cannot find any documentation which would clearly state whether it's in general possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way to connect cross account using transit gateway and this is by sharing the transit gateway [via resource access manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-transit-gateways.html#tgw-sharing). A prerequisite is that both accounts are under the umbrella of an AWS organisation account.

If you are not able to do this then you either need to create a secondary transit gateway in the other account or create a virtual private gateway in account B and associate it to your AWS Account B VPC.

From here you'd then [create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/SetUpVPNConnections.html) your secondary VPN connection.

AWS does not support transitive networking via peering connections. It is a requirement that a traffic packet that reaches the VPC must be terminated in the VPC.

Other solutions people use are:

- Creating a proxy instance in account A that proxies to instance(s) in account B
- Creating a [Transit VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/welcome.html) (More work and risk that the transit gateway)